# No Access message displayed in red after uploading the webpart

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I need to make changes to the control templates in the webpart. So, I took the webpart code from prod to my dev machine and built a test site.

I have uploaded the webpart on to the test site and "No Access" is displayed in the webpart zone. Do I need to follow any special steps to upload a webpart with user controls or control templates.